# php - check if results contain value

Tags: php

I did SQL query.
I would like to check if the results contain the value "xxx".

Is there any php function that support that?

I tried "in_array" but it doesn't work.

```
$stylesQuery = mysql_query("SELECT styleID FROM itins_styles WHERE (itinID = 5)");
    $stylesIndex = mysql_fetch_array($stylesQuery);
    if (in_array ("xxx", $stylesIndex ))
```

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: `Mysql` has been deprecated. Use `mysqli`.

Comment: Use `mysqli` and show your array structure of `$stylesIndex`.

Comment: what do you see with `print_r($stylesIndex);` ?

Comment: if in_array() is not working, perhaps the query might have failed.  Can you please show more code.

Comment: @Roi: you don't know if your query is working.  I suggest that you redo that first line as '$stylesQuery = mysql_query("SELECT styleID FROM itins_styles WHERE (itinID = 5)") or exit(mysql_error($link));'

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `;` in your `mysqli_fetch_array($styleQuery)`.

```
$stylesIndex = mysqli_fetch_array($styleQuery);
```

If your array variable `$stylesIndex` contains the value `xxx` then it should work.

Comment: I'll recommend you to use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql`. It has been deprecated. and check your db manually for value `xxx` where `itinID` is `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in_array() did work.  The function returns **true** when the item is found and **false** otherwise. In the OP's code when in_array() returns false, the if-conditional fails suggesting that  the search string is not in the array.  But, if you know that it should be there, then there might be failure at another point in the code.

As an aside, while mysql is deprecated, and all PHP developers should switch to mysqli, some people don't have that luxury and must work with what their workplace dictates.  The problem here is not mysql but rather the need to heed the Manual's recommendations about basic testing.  Below is code that mainly derives from the Manual (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php)):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$result = null;
$res = null;

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('exp') or exit('Could not select database');

$query =  "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id=0";

$result = mysql_query($query) or exit('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$line = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC );
if (in_array( "US", $line ) ) {
            echo "in array\n";
}

var_dump($line);

// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);
```

This code errors out when I run it because my countries table does not contain an id of zero.  Consequently, the $result does not contain an array of data -- its value is false.  So, in_array() returns false. If I correct the query, then the code runs fine.

Note: having error_reporting() on, can be very helpful when trying to debug code.